# Bootstrap 3: what's the default syntax for always be a certain grid size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a 4 column layout, but I don't want to have to specify that I want each column to be 3 grids wide in small, medium and large resolutions. I think that probably one of these is the default but I guess everyone thinks it's so obvious which is the default one that I haven't found any documentation of which it is (or do I actually have to specify?).

If anyone could offer any tips, it would be most appreciated

Comment: If you just use `.col-sm-3` the column should retain the correct width for small, medium and large resolutions.  Could you give an example of what you are doing now?

Comment: @PM77-1 No its not.  In BS3 you build the page from xs up.  .col-xs-X can be used but the BS3 is defaulted to the xs size.  Then you scale up.  So if you want a 4 column layout from sm all the way up to large, than you simply set .col-sm-3(because 12/3 = 4 columns).  If say you wanted Large to break into 6 cols than you would set .col-sm-3 .col-lg-2

Comment: @PM77-1 no, Pred's answer is flat right, this is how both Bootstrap and Foundation work - mobile first grids.

Comment: @Pred I'd suggest making an answer with your comment, it's totally correct.

Comment: @Dan Thx, looks like you've got it though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### [Grid system: Introduction](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)
>
> - Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, [for example] applying any `.col-md-` class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a `.col-lg-` class is not present.

See also https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E029 , which is about the related error of using redundant grid classes:

> For example, class="col-sm-6" will make the element 6 columns wide on small (sm), medium (md), and large (lg) screens. Therefore, class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" and class="col-sm-6 col-md-6" are both equivalent to class="col-sm-6", which should be preferred since it's simpler and less verbose.

So use only `col-xs-` if you want a width to apply to all screens. Although it's common to use `col-sm-` instead, so that columns stack on `xs` screens, which is often more user-friendly due to XS screens being so narrow.

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap if you set the number of columns for extra small devices, that style will be enabled for extra-smaller and bigger devices, and if you specify another number for medium devices that number will be available for medium and bigger devices, and overwrite any other number of columns.
So in your case, four elements with a class of `col-xs-3` will do the deal.